# Can I get users that checked into my Facebook event or that are at my event?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-events

Using Facebook's JavaScript API I can get my event and the rsvp status of all the attendees.

What I'd like to get is information on who checked into the event, or updated their status to say they were at the event.

Status of person at my event: http://note.io/1maQlip

From what I can tell, I need to loop through the users checkins to see if they were at my event. It doesn't seem like I can query the event for all the users that checked in. Is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I'm afraid there's no other options than looping through the users' checkins for the moment : /

**PS:** @Tobi, this will return the list of attendees, not the list of users who **checked in** at the event (sorry, had to include this in my answer as I can't comment yet).

Comment: That's true... As I understand from TwisterMc's Event, there's no location attached to it (see https://www.facebook.com/events/599978450080176/ and the FQL "select venue,location from event where eid=599978450080176"). Therefore a "checkin at the event" should not be possible from my point of view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FQL table event_member to query for

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/

An FQl query for you event is

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+uid,+rsvp_status+from+event_member+where+eid=599978450080176&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

You can use it via the JS SDK like this:

```
FB.api('https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+uid,+rsvp_status+from+event_member+where+eid=599978450080176&access_token=' + access_token');
```

What you can't do without having the User's user_checkins permission is to crawl for everybody who checked in you Event, which you'd need to gather via an App.